# MySQL Order by Count without Grouping the Result

Tags: mysql, database, backend

I have the following MySQL table:

```
id| title
1 | Apple
2 | Apple
3 | Cherry
4 | Banana
5 | Banana
6 | Apple
```

I want to sort them by the amount of the same fields "title".

So the result should look like this:

```
1 | Apple
2 | Apple
6 | Apple
4 | Banana
5 | Banana
3 | Cherry
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Use counting subquery, join and order by it.

Comment: `select ... left join ... group by title order by count(*)`

Comment: Does someone know the similiar comand for MongoDB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the query below :

```
select 
  mt.id, 
  mt.title 
from mytable mt
join (
  select 
    title, 
    count(*) as ct 
  from mytable 
  group by title
) sq on mt.title = sq.title
order by sq.ct DESC, id ASC
```

[**AND SEE DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=96673600fd3ba5d68ca6259c1d23f94e)